# MockMvc url path not working after spring 4 to 5

Tags: java, spring, spock, web.xml, mockmvc

I'm having below url-pattern in my web.xml

```
<url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
```

MockMvc setup in spock

```
    MockMvc mockMvc

    def setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build()
    }
```

calling my controller api like below in test case

```
        def result = mockMvc.perform(get('/test/warning/term.json")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

`term.json` is pathVariable in controller method.

this spec worked in spring 4. and when I check in debug mode I received in spring controller api only `term` in pathVariable String.

after upgrading to spring 5 getting `term.json` in spring controller api , which is causing the test case failure.

how to fix this?

Comment: Please share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example